# matlab's imshow3d mouse scrolling image visualization in python

Tags: python, image, tkinter, pipeline, mri

Currently, I am trying to build a User Interface with python to visualize MRI images (in numpy) in 'tkinter' Graphic User Interface. 
The feature of mouse scrolling from Matlab's imshow3d is essential but I was not able to find anything like this on web (ex.[https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/mlcdownloads/downloads/submissions/47463/versions/3/screenshot.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fitv.png)).
Does anyone have any idea how I can implement the mouse based slice browsing with tkinter? 
or are there any other gui that I could use to build what I want.